# Is the mentioned code correct for finding out page load time on Firefox?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, page-load-time

Can one find out the page load time by using the following code. If yes then how much will be the accuracy? Is there any more accurate way?

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
Long s= System.currentTimeMillis();
driver.get("https://www.parcelhero.com/en-gb/courier-services/carriers/dhl");
Long e=System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println((e-s)/1000 + " Secs.");
driver.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the Firefox devtools or Firebug. With your method, you are also adding in the browser boot time.

Comment: I'm calculating the "start" time after the browser opens hence browser boot time will not be included.

Comment: You are right. I realized that later and forgot to come back and edit my answer. Can you not just use devtools from your favorite browser? They are built to do stuff like this... and there are many other tools on the web that can do this also. Why reinvent the wheel? You'd have to become and expert in page load times... just use a tool that someone else has created that has the expertise to do it right and it's already been tested.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried executing this JS code in your test:

```
window.performance.timing.loadEventStart - window.performance.timing.navigationStart
```

That should give you the page load time in ms as reported by the developer tools.